# How to display images of a post as a media gallery

Tags: front-end

**Situation**

I used user-frontend API to make user capable of uploading image. But this post page posts the image and the image is visible in media library(which contain other previously submitted posts as well).

**Problem**

I want to display the images associated with a particular post to be displayed as a media gallery.

**Methods I tried**

1. user-frontend API had option of selecting post type as user gallery but even after opting for it its not working properly.
   I think I can use user-post gallery API that allows me to display the images as a gallery, but I dont know how to integrate both the APIs.
   I have some other requirements for which user-frontend API is best choice so cant remove this.

I need some guidance regarding how it can be done maybe through above methods or some meta key or php code.

Kindly ignore the silliness. Its my first wordpress project:)

Direct me if its not possible or if it is possible only without user-frontend API.